# How to make Grails subquery for simple example?

Tags: grails, criteria

I want to fetch the latest records based on a subquery max date value.  This is the entire SQL:

```
select c1.cr_version_id, c1.current_status_id
from cr_version c1
where c1.date_created = (
    select max(date_created)
    from cr_version
    where change_request_id = c1.change_request_id);
```

So simple, but I can't seem to make an equivalent query in Grails using DetachedCriteria.  I thought the subquery might be

```
def subq = CRVersion.where {
  projections {
    groupProperty("changeRequest")
    max("dateCreated")
  }
}
```

But then I can't figure out how to use the subquery from a main query, joining on id.  Everything I try ends up with, at some point:

```
"ERROR: subquery must return only one column"
```

Comment: "I can't figure out how to use the subquery from a main query" - There are numerous examples at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/f1158a73b4127a7aab41608e4ae6e0804079e544/grails-datastore-gorm-test/src/test/groovy/grails/gorm/tests/SubquerySpec.groovy

Answer (score 1):

After much floundering I think I have the core of what I need.  I can build on this:

```
def crvs = CRVersion.where {
 dateCreated == max(dateCreated).of {
    eqProperty("changeRequest", "this.changeRequest")
    setAlias "crVersion"
 }
}.list()
```